# ASP.NET MVC Exclude Namespaces from New View Model Dropdown Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When you add a new view to an ASP.NET MVC project you can strongly type the view by selecting which model class it should work with in the dialog box.  The problem is in that drop down menu it includes all the classes and interfaces from all referenced projects and dlls.  So, I see all the Ninject classes, all the interfaces for my services, etc in that menu.  Is there any way to specify which namespaces to include or a list of namespaces to exclude from that drop down menu?

I realize that this is not a big deal and you can just start typing the name of the class in the box and it will pull up the right one.  I just thought that if there was a place for this it would be nice.  If there isn't, no big deal but I thought I would ask. :)

Comment: On one of the conferences, I heard Phil Haack mentioning this feature. It is possible that VS 11 dev. preview has it (or vs11 RTM will have it) out of the box. Not sure but, it won't allow you to specify which ones are going to be there but that box will only have some sort of specific ones.

Comment: Oh gosh, I hope I recalled it correctly.

Comment: You better hope so because I'm holding you to it and if I don't see it in the future, I'm blaming you. :)

Comment: Then, I should better start nagging at Phil to put this feature:)

Comment: I just give it a try with VS11 Dev. Preview but I got the nasty Model class : dropdown :s

Comment: I am using Model classes in another project referenced with the current MVC project. So in that case I need the listing of all the classes. I separated the Models from current MVC project and added it to another project for ease of use, which is a classlibrary and it is referenced to the current project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really really want this and you are cool with some hacking, try this :)

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.3.01.dll

decompile it - you will find MvcAddViewDialog class, and the GetTypes method in it. Put some filtering in it, recompile, replace, enjoy... but personally, I probably wouldnt :)

Comment: Well, I guess that would work... Since there is no other way to do this I am marking it is the answer but as you said, this probably isn't a good idea! :)